# Adding card to the discard pile

Tags: java

i wanted to add a card to the TOP of discard pile, the the remaining card at the discard pile will automatically get under the new card, i tried many ways to do this but failed, need some guidance here, don't wanna use stack due to the requirements of my project

```
public void setTop(Card c)//add a card to top of discard pile
{       
    if(this.discardCards[0] != null)
    {
        addingCards();
    }
    this.discardCards[0] = c;
    countDiscard++;     
}

public void addingCards()//pushing each cards to the back of the new card
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= countDiscard - 1; i++)
    {
        Card temp = new Card();
        discardCards[i+1] = discardCards[countDiscard - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addingCards` does not do what you think it does. It needs to be something like this:

```
public void addingCards() {
    for (int i = countDiscard; i > 0; i--) {
        discardCards[i] = discardCards[i - 1];
    }
}
```

You need to move all cards up one to make room for the new discard. To do this your loop must start at the end and work backwards.

However, this requires that the discard pile is always big enough to hold all cards.

You would be better off using a [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) which is a double-ended queue so you can add/remove at either end and it will grow to fit your needs.